# eclipse plugin development tool alternative

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna, eclipse-3.6

The plug-in development tool is missing in latest version of Eclipse (Luna).

Windows --> Preferences --> Plugin Development

Any alternative for adding plugin development tool in Eclipse Luna?

Comment: The plugin development tools are still in Luna. Possibly you have downloaded the wrong build of Luna.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your reply, but I have downloaded it from eclipse official site [link](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1/eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

Comment: There are numerous different flavors of Eclipse available for download from the official site, not all of them have the plugin development code. Open 'Install New Software', work with the main Luna site and install 'Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment'